# SQLDeveloper output changes when selecting specific columns

Tags: sql, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Oracle SQL Developer and I am trying to run a query like this

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT id1 CONTRACT_ID1, id2 CONTRACT_ID2 FROM contract_table)
  LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT id1 A_CONTRACT_ID, id2 A_SPECIAL_CONTRACT_ID from special_contract_table_a)
  on (CONTRACT_ID1 = A_CONTRACT_ID)
  LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT id1 B1_CONTRACT_ID, id2 B1_DOCUMENT_ID from document_table_b1)
  ON (CONTRACT_ID2 = B1_CONTRACT_ID)
  LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT id1 B2_CONTRACT_ID, id2 B2_DOCUMENT_ID from document_table_b2)
  ON (A_SPECIAL_CONTRACT_ID = B2_CONTRACT_ID)
  LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT id1 B3_CONTRACT_ID, id2 B3_DOCUMENT_ID from document_table_b3)
  ON (A_SPECIAL_CONTRACT_ID = B3_CONTRACT_ID)
  LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT page PAGE, id1 C1_DOCUMENT_ID, id2 C2_DOCUMENT_ID, id3 C3_DOCUMENT_ID from page_table_c)
  ON (C1_DOCUMENT_ID = B1_DOCUMENT_ID OR C2_DOCUMENT_ID = B2_DOCUMENT_ID OR C3_DOCUMENT_ID = B3_DOCUMENT_ID)
  LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT id2 B1_DOCUMENT_ID_2 from, status B1_DOCUMENT_STATUS from document_table_b1)
  ON (C1_DOCUMENT_ID = B1_DOCUMENT_ID_2)
  LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT id2 B2_DOCUMENT_ID_2 from, status B2_DOCUMENT_STATUS from document_table_b2)
  ON (C2_DOCUMENT_ID = B2_DOCUMENT_ID_2)
  LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT id2 B3_DOCUMENT_ID_2 from, status B3_DOCUMENT_STATUS from document_table_b3)
  ON (C3_DOCUMENT_ID = B3_DOCUMENT_ID_2)
;
```

So basically what this does is, that I select my two base IDs, then get all members of all associated groups and then fetch the status of each of those members (and the status is stored within the group declaration). This works as I expect it as long as I use `SELECT * FROM`. If I change this to `SELECT CONTRACT_ID1, PAGE, B1_DOCUMENT_STATUS, B2_DOCUMENT_STATUS, B3_DOCUMENT_STATUS` the output collapses from 24 lines to 4, showing only the matches for `document_table_b1`.

Any idea how to fix this?

Additional information: DB-Version is Oracle 10g. Oracle SQL Developer Version is 3.2.09.
A comparision between Autotrace and Explainplan shows differences in some of the Access Predicates from `ID_1(+) = ID_2` (Explainplan) to `ID_1 = ID_2` (Autotrace) with both select statements. 
I highly suspect the query optimizer screwing up here. I have not found a way to tinker with its settings yet. Any input in that direction might be helpful.

Comment: Can you try it with explicit aliases for your sub selects?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth done! Better now?

Comment: Eh? What did you change? I was asking you to check if you still get the error when you give your sub queries an explicit alias... I didn't ask you to edit your question... Your code: (select x from foo) left outer join (select y from bar) on (x = y). What I am asking: (select x from foo) **as a** left outer join (select y from bar) **as b** on (a.x = b.y)

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Oh, sorry, read that wrong. Sadly this doesn't affect the output. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 2):

oh, its so unreadable, why do you put each table into select statement

```
SELECT a.id1 as CONTRACT_ID1
,ptc.page as PAGE
,b1.status as B1_DOCUMENT_STATUS
,b2.status as B2_DOCUMENT_STATUS
,b3.status as B3_DOCUMENT_STATUS
FROM 
   contract_table ct 
  LEFT JOIN special_contract_table_a scta  on scta.id1 = ct.id1
  LEFT JOIN document_table_b1 b1 ON b1.id1 = ct.id2
  LEFT JOIN document_table_b2 b2 ON b2.id1 = scta.id2 
  LEFT JOIN document_table_b3 b3 ON b3.id1 = scta.id2
  LEFT JOIN page_table_c ptc ON c.id1 = b1.id1 or c.id2= b2.id1 or c.id3 = b3.id1
  where (YoursPredicateHere)
  --dont understand why you are joining them again 
  --LEFT JOIN document_table_b1 b1_2 ON (C1_DOCUMENT_ID = B1_DOCUMENT_ID_2)
  --LEFT JOIN document_table_b2 b2_2 ON (C2_DOCUMENT_ID = B2_DOCUMENT_ID_2)
  --LEFT JOIN document_table_b3 b3_2 ON (C3_DOCUMENT_ID = B3_DOCUMENT_ID_2)
```

Comment: Can you put a where clause into your syntax?

Comment: and what do you want to put into where clause ?